# How to remove duplicate blog title

Tags: seo, plugin-all-in-one-seo

My blog is www.theprinterdepo.com/blog.

The blog title its in the beginning and at the end, which looks bad for seo efforts, I have a pluggin called ALL In one SEO. Which puts the title of the blog at the end, which is fine.

But I cant find how to remove it from the start of the meta title.

thank you

I suppose this is the code you need:

```
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'left'); ?></title>
```

Comment: What's the relevant code in your theme's `header.php`?

Comment: @brasofilo please check

Answer (score 2):

I normally use WP SEO by Yoast, but here's a troubleshoot:

- what if you use only `wp_title('');` <sup>*(this is a WPSEO requirement)*</sup>
- what do you have as Home Title at the plugin's settings page?
  [image]
- search your theme's `functions.php` for a similar hook, and disable if found:
  `add_filter( 'wp_title', 'twentyten_filter_wp_title', 10, 2 );`
- dig into WordPress forums for similar issues: http://wordpress.org/search/all-in-one-seo-pack+wp_title?forums=1

Answer (score 1):

Either use `wp_title()` only, or add this line to your theme's functions.php file:

`remove_all_filters('wp_title');`